# Remove subset in a set

Tags: ocaml

Remove a subset in a list of lists, for example: given `ls` has type `int list list`, the result of `ls` is a `result` function: `int list list -> int list list`

```
ls: [[1;2;3;4];[1;2];[1;2;3];[0]]
```

result of `ls` is: `[[1;2;3;4];[0]]`

I have:

```
module Int_set = Set.Make (struct
                              type t = int
                              let compare = compare
                            end)

let set_of_list = List.fold_left (fun acc x ->
                                  Int_set.add x acc) Int_set.empty

let result ls =
  match ls with
  | [] -> print_string "nothing\n"
  | l1 :: ls' ->
     List.iter
       (fun l2 ->
        let s1 = set_of_list l1 in
        let s2 = set_of_list l2 in
        if Int_set.subset s1 s2
        then
          (*remove s1*)
         .....   
       ) ls'
```

Could you please help me to figure out how to write the remove function?

Comment: I want to remove all the subset inside a set. Is it not clear?

Comment: Recursively? Independently of the order of appearance in the list?

Comment: I have solved the problem. Sorry to make you confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Int_Set.diff`.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I still dont understand why I can use this function?

Answer (score 0):

I have make an example with the List data structure that give me the result I wanted.

Here is the code:

```
let map_filter l1 ls = List.map (List.filter (fun x -> List.mem x l1))ls

let result_filter ls =
  match ls with
  | [] -> []
  | l1 :: ls' -> map_filter l1 ls'

let result ls =
    let ls' = result_filter ls in
    List.filter (fun l -> not (List.mem l ls')) ls
```